# Redirect bash output to new file every 10 seconds

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a COM_port, which I listen like this:

```
nc -l -p 1234.
```

So, I want to redirect the output to a file, at that every 10 seconds to a new file. 
I know how to redirect the flow to a file:

```
nc -l -p 1234 > file.txt
```

But how to write the flow to new file every 10 seconds? (for first 10 seconds file_10.txt, for second file_20.txt and so on).
I'm afraid of loosing the data from flow.
How is it possible to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: If a connection lasts longer than 10 seconds (or spans a change event), do you want part of the input logged to one file and part to another, or are you switching based only on the time of the initial connection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- IMPORTANT! bash, not /bin/sh; must also not run with "sh scriptname".

file="file_$((SECONDS / 10))0.txt"        # calculate our initial filename
exec 3>"$file"                            # and open that first file

exec 4< <(nc -l -p 1234)                  # also open a stream coming from nc on FD #4

while IFS= read -r line <&4; do           # as long as there's content to read from nc...
  new_file="file_$((SECONDS / 10))0.txt"  # calculate the filename for the current time
  if [[ $new_file != "$file" ]]; then     # if it's different from our active output file
    exec 3>$new_file                      #   then open the new file...
    file=$new_file                        #   and update the variable.
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "$line" >&3               # write our line to whichever file is open on FD3
done
```

Comment: Perfect!
* I can write the same script in Python, what I should prefer for performance ?
Thank you.

Comment: Python will have better performance than bash; Golang will have better performance than Python (and is what I'd use if this was going to be processing very high volumes).

Comment: Wow! What about C? is it better than Golang? Many thanks!

Comment: "Better"? That's a tough call -- Golang is less prone to security vulnerabilities caused by pointer abuse or improperly-sized buffers; C will compile to smaller binaries, both are going to have high enough performance to make the difference for this kind of use case effectively moot. I know both, and -- as aforementioned -- for this particular program, I personally would use Go (unless the intent was to use this on an embedded system where binary size matters).